# Using react-redux action's payload as my redux state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

The situation that I have in my react-native app is the following:

- I read a very complex XML file (with deep hierarchy) in my action creator (using react-native's fetch and redux-thunk), convert it to an object and fire an action.
- The reducer's state is identical in structure to this object.
- In the reducer, usually in such situations, I use the current state and set the changed fields (where the action's payload differ from the current state) in the new state
- However, in the current situation I am having, the XML file changes only twice a day, and the change is in many fields, so there is no point in checking which of the fields have been changed and set the state selectively but use the new payload as the new state.

My question: can I use the payload created in the action as my new state, or do I need to deep clone it to the new state?

(The reason I can think of that using the payload may not work is that it is in temporary storage that may be reclaimed when the reducers are done handling the action.)

Comment: Yeah you should be able to just `return payload` in that `case`

Comment: @Tony Thanks. Doesn't this mean that no storage is reclaimed which may lead to redux apps using lots of storage after running for a while?

Comment: What do you mean by having storage reclaimed? The reducers simply returns the new state, it can be any object you want it to be. I don't see any reason to not use the payload

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: good manual https://decembersoft.com/posts/redux-hero-part-2-actions-and-their-consequences-a-fun-introduction-to-redux-actions/